# angular-translate, issue with static loader (file loader)

Tags: angularjs

I'm working with angular-tranlate.

I got it working with the $translateProvider.translations('en', en_translations); where en_translations is the json with the mapping.

Now I'm having a problem when trying to use static files:

```
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');

$translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
    prefix: 'locale-',
    suffix: '.json'
});
```

I'm receiving this error:

```
    Error: Unknown provider: $translateStaticFilesLoaderProvider <- $translateStaticFilesLoader

throw Error("Unknown provider: " + path.join(' <- '));
```

I have my locale-en.json file in the same location as the scrips file.
and it looks like this:

```
{
            "WELCOME": "Welcome",
            "LANG": {
                    "LABEL": "Language",
                    "EN": "English",
                    "ES": "Spanish"
                },
            "LOGOFF": "Log Off",
            "PROFILE": "Profile"
}
```

Any ideas?? thanks!!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

you need to add the static files loader js to your index file. 
you can find it [here](https://github.com/PascalPrecht/bower-angular-translate-loader-static-files)

just put this in index.html

```
<script src="js/libs/angular/angular-translate-loader-static-files.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks man!!! that did the trick. I thought that angular-translate included all since the first example with $translateProvider.translations('en', en_translations); was working..
Thanks again.